# Smooth Painting in a SurfaceView

Tags: android, drawing, paint, surfaceview

I'm working on a paint-like app, but I've run it to some troubles.

I know I have re-draw all the objects each frame, but this in turn makes performance slow further on when many objects are visible.

I've also noticed that clearing the background only once, then adding objects to be drawn to the surface when painting is active makes the screen flash almost to the point of inducing epilepsy.

So what is the best way to make a paint app 100% smooth no matter how many objects that are drawn?

Epilepsy-inducing code:

```
public void run()
{
    while (running)
    {

        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        if (drawObjectsToAdd.size() == 0)
            continue;

        drawing = true;

        Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();

        if (redrawBackground)
        {
            c.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            redrawBackground = false;
        }   

        drawObjects.addAll(drawObjectsToAdd);
        drawObjectsToAdd.clear();

        for (DrawObject draw : drawObjects)
        {
            draw.Draw(c, paint);
        }

        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        drawing = false;
    }
}
```

this adds a new object once it's been added outside of the thread, but it makes the screen flash so much it gives me headaches - and I only redraw the background once.

Smooth at first but becomes laggy after a while, probably due to having to add hundreds and hundreds of objects in the end:

```
public void run()
{
    while (running)
    {
        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        if (drawObjectsToAdd.size() > 0)
        {
            drawObjects.addAll(drawObjectsToAdd);
            drawObjectsToAdd.clear();

            redraw = true;
        }

        if (clear)
        {
            drawObjectsToAdd.clear();
            drawObjects.clear();
            redraw = true;
            clear = false;
        }

        if (!redraw)
            continue;

        drawing = true;

        Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();

        c.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

        for (DrawObject draw : drawObjects)
        {
            try
            {
                draw.Draw(c, paint);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }


        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

        drawing = false;
        redraw = false;
    }
}
```

I, at least for this app wanna store all the objects that are added so it doesn't matter how it's painted as long as it's smooth all the way. Preferably, add a circle - it will render a new Bitmap on to the surface, instead of having to redraw lots of objects each frame - instead store them but do not add objects already drawn.

**UPDATE**

Pseudo-Code of how I want it to be:

```
If no background is drawn
   Draw background color
If new items have been added
   Draw only new items to the background
   Store new items in objects list
```

This way, we'll only draw the background once. When a new item is added, only draw that item to the existing surface. When the objects increases, looping through every item will reduce performance greatly and it will not be pleasant to work with.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
private void Draw()
{
    while (running)
    {

        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        if (picture == null)
        {
            picture = new Picture();
            Canvas c = picture.beginRecording(getWidth(), getHeight());
            c.drawARGB(255,  255,  255,  255);
            picture.endRecording();
        }

        if (drawObjectsToAdd.size() > 0)
        {
            drawObjects.addAll(drawObjectsToAdd);
            drawObjectsToAdd.clear();

            Canvas c = picture.beginRecording(getWidth(), getHeight());

            for (DrawObject draw : drawObjects)
            {
                draw.Draw(c, paint);
            }

            picture.endRecording();
            drawObjects.clear();

        }

        Canvas c2 = holder.lockCanvas();
        c2.drawPicture(picture);

        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c2);
    }
}
```

This last method from **Update 2** makes it render all the lines like the "Snake game" when adding circles. Looks like a moving snake on a background, where some of it's circles disappear one frame and others don't the next. If I skip to redraw each frame, it will instead vary which of these circles that are visible.

Comment: how many objects are we talking about ?

Comment: As many as needed. It's a paint app, so preferably you should paint how much you want without hindering performance. My only idea so far is to: add an object, get the bitmap from the view. When another object is added, redraw the bitmap and then add the new object on top of the bitmap. This way it will only redraw a bitmap each frame instead of millions of potential objects.

Comment: but what about modification of existing items, undo etc ?

Comment: Why I store all the objects added, then when that mode is enabled you just check the closest object to the point where you wanna "Undo" or "Erase" and remove those. But as of now, with my implementation the "SurfaceView.getDrawingCache()" does not return anything. I call it a "SurfaceViewThread extends SurfaceView implements Runnable", maybe I go about it wrong. But any other methods I've tried to implement hasn't been working correctly.

Comment: But yeah, that implementation might also get performance demanding. But I've found now way around the performance trouble, since my method works but after adding lots of objects it becomes slow. And I can't find any information on how to just draw the background once, then draw only newly added objects to the surface without having to redraw the whole screen and adding every item that's already been added.

Comment: did you think about a Picture ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html

Comment: Looks promising, can't find out whether or not to use it on a SurfaceView or how to implement it. I tried changing my holder.lockCanvas() and such to having a Picture there, but nothing's happening.

Comment: If I use this algorithm: If new items exists, add them and set variable redraw to true. If redraw is true: Call beginRecording() on Picture, draw all new objects to the picture's canvas. Call endRecording(); clear all objects that's been painted from the list (still store them someplace else). Unlock the canvas from the SurfaceView and call drawPicture(picture), then unlockCanvasAndPost(). This makes some items appear sometimes, sometimes other items. Like 5 circles appear one time, then 5 other circles appear another time.

Comment: i would keep objects in bunches for example 64 objects per Picture, so keep new objects in a list which you iterate and draw all of them, it the list size is bigger than 64 add them all to a new Picture, so it means two lists: one for Pictures and the second for new objects

Comment: Still, even adding one or two makes it render it all wrong. When I drag my finger on the screen, some appears, other's don't, then the other's appear and some don't. When I stop moving my finger, some are only visible. Possibly due to some of them being rendered on the backbuffer and the rest on the frontbuffer. Not sure how it's best to implement this. And any search containing "picture" and draw is to vague and thus difficult to find a good tutorial about this with Picture in mind.

Comment: Updated my post with my implementation of this, but now it looks like a moving motion on the background. No matter how many circles, rectangles, lines I have it's the same. Instead of the background flashing, it's the objects doing it.

Comment: Are you aware that the "framebuffer" is double- or triple-buffered?  It's not a single buffer that you're repeatedly drawing into, but a series of buffers.  So if in frame #1 the renderer draws the background and objects 1-10, and in frame #2 draws objects 5-12, you're going to see one complete frame, followed by a frame with just objects 5-12.  You need to render the full scene every time.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But that's why I've tried to draw all objects each frame (slow) and why I've tried to only paint into the Picture only when new objects have been added, otherwise render it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

what about that Picture implementation? increase MAX_DRAWERS to some reasonable value and see how it works

```
class SV extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {
    private static final int MAX_DRAWERS = 8;

    private boolean mRunning = true;
    private List<Picture> mPictures = new LinkedList<Picture>();
    private List<Drawer> mDrawers = new LinkedList<Drawer>();
    private Paint mPaint;

    public SV(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(0xffffff00);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mRunning = false;
        notify();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Drawer drawer = new Drawer(event.getX(), event.getY());
        mDrawers.add(drawer);

        if (mDrawers.size() > MAX_DRAWERS) {
            Picture picture = new Picture();
            Canvas canvas = picture.beginRecording(getWidth(), getHeight());
            mPaint.setAlpha(0xbb);
            for (Drawer dr : mDrawers) {
                dr.draw(canvas, mPaint);
            }
            picture.endRecording();
            mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);
            mPictures.add(picture);
            mDrawers.clear();
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent new Picture");
        }
        notify();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        while (mRunning) {
//            Log.d(TAG, "run wait...");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            if (mRunning) {
//                Log.d(TAG, "run woke up");
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(0xff0000ff);
                for (Picture picture : mPictures) {
                    picture.draw(canvas);
                }
                for (Drawer drawer : mDrawers) {
                    drawer.draw(canvas, mPaint);
                }
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "run bye bye");
    }

    class Drawer {
        private float x;
        private float y;
        public Drawer(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 8, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a working method, but why can't I use a single Picture to store everything on? Tried implementing that with your code, but it becomes just a moving dot whenever I touch the screen. It's a little faster than rendering all objects each frame.

Comment: because you cannot both recording (adding new stuff) and drawing at one time, at least i think it is so... but when you have too many Pictures you can combine them into one SuperHiperMegaPicture

Comment: Well, isn't that what I'm already doing except recording to multiple pictures already? And as far as I can read the code it waits for the notify() while recording new data into the picture either way, so it doesn't get drawn. Also, not sure where to set the default Background Color without adding anything, with all these threaded methods. Can't exactly call it in the constructor, and it's already being notified in the surfaceCreated, and instead of having an onTouch event I have an Add method that does the same.

Comment: so instead of having mPictures you can have a Bitmap which will be drawn with one Canvas.drawBitmap and updated in the place where mDrawers is clear()ed

Comment: I just tried a different method where: Create Picture, if "this.picture != null" draw it in to the new picture, then add the DrawObject, EndRecording store it as "this.picture" and Notify(). Yields about the same performance as the other methods, but with less data stored in the app. But, after a couple of hundred circles - it still becomes slow. Not sure why. It's at this point only rendering MAX_DRAWERS of DrawObject and mPictures.size() number of pictures, but the performance is very noticeable reducing. Or the way I implemented my method. About the same as before.

Comment: if its still slow then use a Bitmap, pro: its fast, con: uses more memory, disables undo options

Comment: The app that I'm working on probably requires more performance than an undo method whatsoever. I'll try and work my way around it, see how it goes.

Comment: btw do you use a hardware acceleration ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49600/discussion-between-deukalion-and-pskink)

Answer (score 0):

You generate your list of objects each and every frame, just to discard it after drawing. Why? Generate your list of draw objects once, then draw them.

That's all you need for your drawing thread...

```
public void run() {
while (running)
{

    Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();

    c.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

    for (DrawObject draw : drawObjects)
    {
        try
        {
            draw.Draw(c, paint);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }


    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

}
```

}

Comment: I don't generate my list of drawing objects, if the screen is being "redrawn" while adding a new DrawObject I add it to "drawObjectsToAdd", then once the drawing has been completed it checks that list and adds it to be added. All I see before me is a more buggy solution that crashes for me. I also need to check if the SurfaceHolder is valid, or not skip the loop (otherwise it crashes immediately). And by adding objects directly to my drawObjects makes the app crash after a few times (because it probably "is" rendering objects while I still add it to the list), why I use "drawObjectsToAdd".

Comment: Touch the screen, add an object. But add it to a seperate list that only gets checked once drawing has been completed. If new objects to be drawn are found, add it it to the draw list and clear that list. Then redraw with all the objects in drawObjects. I never discard it after drawing. All objects are still present in "drawObjects" only that newer objects are added to a seperate list so it doesn't collide with the "for" loop in the middle of the thread. Since they're running on seperate thread, when I call my method "Add" and the the thread that's doing all the painting.

Comment: ...also, when the drawing has been completed and no new objects has been added - it is not necessarily needed to redraw the Surface. I added to your method: if the SurfaceHolder isn't valid: continue; add drawObjectsToAdd to drawObjects. From the start of the app it lags behind. With my method, the most recent added object is exactly where my finger is while with this method it's lagging behind. If just putting your finger on the screen and drawing, no matter what it is.